# \circled and \rhombus-ed similar to \boxed?

Tags: equations, amsmath

I am taking a class where the instructor has asked us to put a circle, rectangle, or rhombus around givens, dependent, and independent variables.

The box is easy, I just use `\boxed{x}` from `amsmath`.

Is there a similarly easy solution for circling or rhombus-ing?

[image: Crude Inkscape demonstration.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather easy to do that with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\newcommand{\tboxed}[2][inner sep=1pt]{\ifmmode
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer
sep=0pt]{\node[draw,#1](X){\ensuremath{#2}};}
\else
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer
sep=0pt]{\node[draw,#1](X){#2};}
\fi
}
\newcommand{\circled}[2][inner sep=1pt]{\ifmmode
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer sep=0pt]{\node[circle,draw,#1](X){\ensuremath{#2}};}
\else
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer sep=0pt]{\node[circle,draw,#1](X){#2};}
\fi
}
\newcommand{\rhombed}[2][inner sep=1pt]{\ifmmode
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer sep=0pt]{\node[diamond,draw,#1](X){\ensuremath{#2}};}
\else
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer sep=0pt]{\node[diamond,draw,#1](X){#2};}
\fi
}
\newcommand{\trapezed}[2][inner sep=1pt]{\ifmmode
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer sep=0pt]{\node[trapezium,draw,
trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,#1](X){\ensuremath{#2}};}
\else
\tikz[baseline=(X.base),outer sep=0pt]{\node[trapezium,draw,
trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,#1](X){#2};}
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\boxed{x} \circled{y} \rhombed{z} \trapezed{u}
\[ \circled{z}~=~
\frac{\tboxed[rounded corners]{x}\trapezed[rounded corners,inner sep=2pt]{y}}{\circled{u}}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Added `mathmode` treatment and corrected the rhombus.

Comment: I really like this. Even when I tried to break it by adding subscripts, the shapes expand naturally. I also like how it preserves the lines, but expands the spacing between symbols when necessary. Much better than anything I would have come up with!

Comment: @MichaelMolter Thanks! But I think that all the credits should go to Till Tantau ;-)

Comment: Do you know how to make the rhombus in the image? Otherwise I can meddle with it some more.

Comment: I guess its more of a parallelogram...

Comment: @MichaelMolter Sure. Sorry, I didn't look carefully enough. I made an update.

Comment: Can you explain how one would make [outer sep=2pt] the default? I've tried changing "outer sep=0pt" to "outer sep=2pt" in code lines 6 and 9 (and subsequent), but that didn't do it.  Again, I want to thank you for your work.This macro has been extremely handy for a course I am taking.

Comment: @MichaelMolter Could you perhaps be a bit more specific and provide one complete example that shows what you've tried? (After the updated `tikzmark` library appeared, I believe one can improve and simplify the answer quite a bit. But I would like to know what you've tried in detail, and also understand what you want to achieve. You could just append this to your question if a comment is not sufficient. Generally you can append such things with `\tikzset{every node/.append style={...}}` but I am not sure I understand your request.)